# UI for Adding Products to an Opportunity

Tags: visualforce, lightning, opportunity, mobile, product

I need a UI for adding products to an opportunity, which can be used during specific high volume times. I can't seem to find anything appropriate on App Exchange. Attempting to create a flow won't work, since I can't get more than one button to show on the screen. I'm a novice when it comes to building Visualforce pages.

Below is an image of what I'm trying to do. While on a tablet, if a user pushes any of the buttons to the left of the screen, the quantity tallies in the right column. The price for products would never change. Products during this high volume time would always go to one specific Account. Clicking the 'add products' button would add products in build to the account opportunity.

Has anyone seen anything close to this? Or is there a good direction I should go in?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using Flow with [this installable screen component that generates multiple buttons](https://unofficialsf.com/fsc-navigation-button/). Also [this video](https://unofficialsf.com/how-to-use-collection-operators-in-assignment-element/) shows some good button bar implementations.